# how to create datatables with basic if else

Tags: if-statement, datatables

```
"columns": [
    { "data": "no" },
    { "data": "id_perangkat" },
    { "data": "tanggal" },
    { "data": "nilai" },

    "render": function (data, type, row) {
         if (type==='GET'){
         if (data.nilai >== 1) { return "Apple"; }
         else if (data.nilai >== 51) { return "Banana"; }
         else return "tidak ada data";
     }
   }
]
```

i trying this code, but it's table show blank
i wish table can show the data with if condition

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `type==='GET'`? The `type` parameter of the `column.render` function will contain specific values, as documented [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). Scroll down that page to the description for `function render( data, type, row, meta )` and read what the `type` parameter means - and what its valid values are. You can see examples of how `type` can be used on [this page](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#Computed-values).

Comment: You can also take a look at how the `data` parameter works, in the same section of the documentation as the `type` parameter. You can see for yourself what values are assigned to `data`, `type` and `row` by adding `console.log( data );` (and so on) statements to the body of the function, before the start of the first `if( ... )` statement.